# Implementing a generic function for mocking purposes in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, generics

In my app I have an interface for classes / libraries responsible for fetching data from external sources. This is how it looks like:

```
export interface IWebFetchSerivce {
  get<T>(url: string): Promise<T>;
}
```

in the app's code I use `axios` that has the `get()` method so it correctly implements the `IWebFetchSerivce` interface.

Now, in my tests I don't want to use axios and call extenall APIs but rather mock it and return a static resource

```
class AxiosMock implements IWebFetchSerivce {
  get<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
    return Promise.resolve('Main Page');
  }
}
```

when i write a class like that, TypeScript gives me an error:

```
error TS2322: Type 'Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<T>'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.

        return Promise.resolve('Main Page');
```

I learned that if the method in the interface is generic, its implementation has to be generic as well. I guess that returning always a string makes is not generic. I tried to make a type assertion with adding `as T` at the end of the return statement but it just gave me a different error.

What would be the proper implementation of this mocking class so that it properly implements the generic function, but at the same time returns a predefined value?

Comment: Since it's for tests purposes, if you wanna use some force try  ' 'Main Page' as Unknown as T' might work.

Comment: A method like `get<T>(url: string): Promise<T>;` is impossible to implement safely, as it purports to be able to return a `Promise<T>` for any `T` specified by the caller, but such specification happens only in the type system and is completely [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) from the emitted JavaScript.  Since that is inherently unsafe there is no way to properly implement it.  The best you can do is the above-suggested `"Main Page" as unknown as T` or the terser `"Main Page" as any`

Comment: thank you @jcalz - this is exactly the solution I was looking for